# displaying React FullCalendar with weekNumberCalculation function

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, week-number

I am looking to pass a function into FullCalendar's weekNumberCalculation option. Can anyone give me an example of how this can be done?

I read on the documentation that the function must accept a Date, but I'm not sure which Date value needed to be passed in here. Is it just any date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a callback function. You supply the definition of the function, but it's fullCalendar's code which will actually execute it. When it does that, fullCalendar will pass a relevant date in.

You will never call the function from your own code, so don't need to worry about that. All you need to do is make your function process that date and return a suitable week number back to fullCalendar.

So you just write something like this in your fullCalendar options:

```
weekNumberCalculation: function(date) {
  //here you would do some calculations, making use of the date supplied by fullCalendar....
  return 1; //return a week number (obviously in reality this will be the result of your calculations)
}
```

Comment: Thank you :D. Is it also possible to indicate specific week within a month that I want to display the week number?

Comment: You could try returning nothing from the function, for the weeks you don't want to display, but I don't know if it will error or not

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it doesnt show error. FYI, the value displayed for those weeks that I dont want is 'NaN' instead.

Comment: Well that's kind of an error really. I guess fullCalendar assumes that what you return will be a valid number. So I think what you want isn't really possible

Comment: I found something else on the doc actually - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/week-number-render-hooks. So if I want to display customised content in place of the simple weekNumber display, I can use weekNumberContent option, where I can pass in a string, an object, or a function, according to this part of the doc here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection.

Comment: Ah yes that's a good idea I hadn't thought of that. Have you been able to make it work?

Comment: Yeah it works fine :D

Comment: I have voted to get this question re-opened, and then you could add your version as the answer :-)